# kernel modules missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, kernel

I'm not sure what happened, but I upgrade my ubuntu system to 12.04 and now something is hosed, I can't boot into my 3.2.0-24-generic kernel, all it does is load up to the login screen and then I loose control of my mouse and keyboard.

I have to boot into a previous kernel for anything to work.

I  tried running some updates to my system, but I was getting an error

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/modules.dep: Not a directory
```

So I checked out the `/lib/modules` directory to see whats going on

```
└─(23:24:%)── ls -la                                           ──(Thu,May03)─┘
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root        4096 May  2 23:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 27 root       root       12288 May  3 23:22 ../
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root        4096 May  3 00:26 2.6.31-22-generic/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root        4096 Jan 19 12:52 2.6.32-28-generic/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root        4096 May  3 23:01 2.6.38-13-generic/
c-wS-w---x  1 1744863507 161358036 172, 0 May  6  1927 3.2.0-24-generic
```

WHOA, what in the world happened to my 3.2.0-24 kernel?  I don't know

any one know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the kernel package yet?

Comment: That looks like a corrupted filesystem.  I would strongly recommend booting to single user and `fsck` the disk before anything else.  Then reinstall the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reinstall your 3.2.0.-24by forcing if it does not install cleanly the next time.